# having difficulty understanding assert macro

Tags: c++, algorithm, macros, assert

I recently found this snippet of code and i'm a bit confused.

```
#ifdef LOCAL //  chk -> fake assert
    #define dbg(...) cerr << "Line(" << __LINE__ << ") -> [" << #__VA_ARGS__ << "]: [", DBG(__VA_ARGS__)
    #define chk(...) if (!(__VA_ARGS__)) cerr << "Line(" << __LINE__ << ") -> function(" \
         << __FUNCTION__  << ") -> CHK FAILED: (" << #__VA_ARGS__ << ")" << "\n", exit(0);
#else
    #define dbg(...) 0
    #define chk(...) 0
#endif
```

I clearly understand what the debug does but I have no idea what "chk" does and how I should use  this in my code. Thank you

Comment: If you understand `dbg`, what is the reason why `chk` is not understandable?  One thing -- it kills your application if you use it.

Comment: Did you try:
`chk(false);`, `chk(true);` and `dbg("hello");` should be pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

*dbg* prints message to `cerr` in every case together with macro arguments regardless of whether arguments evaluate to `true` or `false`

On the other hand *chk* macro prints message only in case when macro arguments evaluate to false and then calls `exit`